# How to switch from wireless to wired connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, wired

Common problem for me: I connect my laptop to building WiFi. Later, I go to my office, which has a wired connection. I plug in, but no wired connection occurs. If I had not already been connected to WiFi, the wired connection would work fine. Is there a simple way to switch to wired without rebooting (which is my current solution)?

I am running Ubuntu 18.04. I tried turning off the wireless connection, but this does not seem to work--it seems to be not looking for any wired connections once a wireless connection has been made.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see your Ethernet adapter in the dropdown at the top right of the screen (Network Manager)?  Did you click it to enable the connection?  By default you have to initialize the connection *once* and then it SHOULD automatically connect to the Ethernet when you plug it in using DHCP.

Comment: For me the menu seems to be in the bottom right of the screen (since I'm using cinnamon?).  In any case, it shows "wired--cable unpluged" at the very top of the menu and then below that wireless and vpn connections. The wire is definitely plugged in.

Comment: Also, I have connected many times before, so that automatic connection you refer to is probably set up now. (It is automatic when there is not an existing WiFi connection.)

Comment: You sure the wire you're using is live?  You sure the jack it's connected to is live?  At my workplace, unless your jack is physically activated, it's left inactive until we have a reason to activate it, this us a protection method to protect corporate networks.

Comment: I use the wire almost every day, so it should be active. Whenever I restart my machine and plug it in, the connection works just fine.